# Process requires to press <enter> to continue. Is it possible to do using Mono GTK#?

Tags: c#, linux, shell, process, gtk#

I am trying to run the "dh_make" shell command, using GTK# in Mono. The problem is: dh_make requires to the process start working, to press the key . I don't know if it is possible to do using C#. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the relation between C# and `dh_make` ? You should explain more what you want to achieve, and what did you code so far.

Comment: Maybe you might connect `pipe(2)` between your GTK# program and `dh_make` using the GTK# wrapping of  `g_spawn_async_with_pipes` then send a `\n` on the pipe.

Comment: I was trying to create a app using GTK# in MonoDevelop, that build .deb packages with non-binary files, for academic purposes. Running dh_make is a step for the generation of .deb package. I am using the Process class to run this command, but I got a problem: after the dh_make is initialized, for the process start working on the packaging I must press <enter> key on the terminal and I don't know if it is possible to do using C#.

Comment: Then my comment about `g_spawn_async_with_pipes` is relevant to you. You'll need two pipes (one for input, one for output) at least to communicate with your `dh_make` process.

Comment: Thank you, but could you give me some tutorial link about how can I do it using C#? I could not find it in Google.

Comment: I am understanding "academic purposes" as "homework". Then you should tag your question as such.

Comment: No, it isn't a homewrok.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it definitely is possible to emulate an 'enter' pressing to a process as an input from the user. The following code would do just that, by starting dh_make as a seperate process, directing its standard input into the output of the creating process, and sending 'enter' as input to the dh_make process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "dh_make";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "(put here any command line arguments you need)";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.Start();
System.IO.StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;

// The following will put an 'Enter' on the first dh_make request for user input
myStreamWriter.WriteLine(" ");
```

I am currently using this in several pieces of code and it works very well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You will also want to include myProcess.WaitForExit() at the end. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, you need to have pipes communicating with the `dh_make` process using [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html). With Gtk, you probably will need to master the [main event loop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) and adding child watching with [g_child_watch_add](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-add) and channel watching with [g_io_add_watch](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch). You'll probably have to use two channels (i.e. pipes), one for the input of `dh_make` and another one for its output.

If you have no precise idea of what [pipes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) are, consider reading a good [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) book. Gtk's main loop is doing the multiplexing [poll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) for you.

If you want to understand how these low-level Gtk/Glib functions are glued to Gtk#, study [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) documentation and eventually look inside its source code (perhaps using `grep` on the source code of `Gtk#`). Gtk# has probably some test or demo or example code related to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "'/home/"+user+"/pacotes/"+nome_pacote.Text+"-1.0/'";
        process.StartInfo.FileName="dh_make";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments="-n -s";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        System.IO.StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(" ");
        process.WaitForExit();
```

On debugging I got the following error:  *Odd character '>', expected a '=' after attribute name 'unknown' of element 'filename*. Do you know what could be?

Comment: I get this error when I jump to the line "myStreamWriter.WriteLine(" ");".